# Why am I unable to enter the php page via the AJAX call?

Tags: php, html, ajax

My HTML and PHP code is given below, I'm able to receive the mail.value in txt but faltering during the AJAX call, it doesn't even enter error.

Can someone help me rectify the error so I'm able to pass the AJAX call and get the value sent to the php page.

There is the same piece of code which works for me on the login page, but it it isn't working for the newaccount page.

HTML code:

```
<script src="jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
<script>

function check()
    {
       var mail=document.getElementById("mail");
       var password=document.getElementById("password");
       var First_name=document.getElementById("First_name");
       var Last_name=document.getElementById("Last_name");
       var st_number=document.getElementById("st_number");
       var st_name=document.getElementById("st_name");
       var zip=document.getElementById("zip");
       var Phone=document.getElementById("phone");
       var Gender=document.getElementsByClassName("gender");
       var age=document.getElementById("age");
       var account=document.getElementById("account");
       document.getElementById("txt").innerHTML=mail.value;

        $.ajax({
url: "newacc.php?",
data: { 
    "account": account.value,
    "Email": mail.value,
    "Pass": password.value,
    "FirstName": First_name.value,
    "LastName": Last_name.value,
    "Phone":Phone.value,
    "age": age.value,
    "Gender": Gender.value,
    "st_number": st_number.value,
    "st_name": st_name.value,
    "zip": zip.value
},
    cache: false,
    type: "POST",
    success: function(response) {
     document.getElementById("txt").innerHTML= "this is it";

    },
    error: function(xhr) {
      document.getElementById("txt").innerHTML= "No";
    }
});


  }


</script>
```

PHP code:

```
<?php
echo "Check";
$servername ="localhost";
$username = "root";
$password ="root";
$dbname ="pitt_store";
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password,$dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected so successfully";
$account = $_POST["account"];
echo "The address is $account";
$email = $_POST["Email"];
echo "The email is $email";
$password = $_POST["Pass"];
echo "The Password is $password";
$first_name = $_POST["FirstName"];
echo "The FNAME is $first_name";
$last_name = $_POST["LastName"];
echo "The LNAME is $last_name";
$phone = $_POST["Phone"];
echo "The phone number is $phone";
$age = $_POST["age"];
echo "The age is $age";
$gender = $_POST["Gender"];
echo "The gender is $gender";
$st_number = $_POST["st_number"];
echo "The street number is $st_number";
$st_name = $_POST["st_name"];
echo "The street name is $st_name";
$zip = $_POST["zip"];
echo "The zip is $zip";

/*$sql= "INSERT INTO Customer(first_name,last_name,email,password) VALUES('$first_name'
,'$last_name','$email','$password')";
if ($conn->query($sql) == TRUE)
{
  echo "Record added successfully";
} 
else 
{
  echo "Error adding record: " . $conn->error;
}*/
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: Why don't you open dev tools on the newaccount page and inspect the AJAX call there? Maybe not all the data is being sent. That's the front-end, though. If your script is throwing errors, you'll have to locate the error log in your environment to get anywhere with debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this was happening was because one of my parameters was giving an undefined value.